# Extra junk value when converting float into string

Tags: swift

I was playing with the floats and explicit conversion of the floats into desired types. What I'm getting is when you convert a float into string, there is some junk data that comes along. Why is that happening ?

Heres my code :

```
let a:Float = 5.23

var fName = "john"
var lName = "doe"
var fullName = fName + lName
var mixedString = fullName + String(a)
print(mixedString)
```

This gives `johndoe5.23000001907349` as output. What is going on here with the extra `1907349`

Comment: Consider the bit depth and how it limits the accuracy. There is an unlimited range of real numbers and only limited bits for storage.  That accounts for all current computer system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Float` type isn't terribly precise, so you're getting a little extra garbage from the imprecision. If you omit the `Float` type declaration, you'll get a `Double` instead, which won't have this problem.

```
let a = 5.23

var fName = "john"
var lName = "doe"
var fullName = fName + lName
var mixedString = fullName + String(a)
print(mixedString)
// prints "johndoe5.23"
```

Comment: You can also declare a as a `Double` explicitly: `let a: Double = 5.23`

Comment: But doesn't this create security problems ?

Comment: How would that create security problems? A double and a float both represent floating point numbers, the double just has twice as many bits to hold the number, so you get a lot more precision (and range). There shouldn't be any security impact of using one type over the other.

Comment: I guess he meant using Float and getting 5.23000001907349 instead of 5.23 causes security problems.

Comment: @GokhanArik Yes. Thats what i meant. Its storing garbage value. So it can be a security threat ?

Comment: I suppose from the perspective that results are less predicable due to the lower precision, it could be a security issue. You certainly shouldn't use a `Float` as an iterator. In any case, in Swift at least, `Double` is the preferred type for floating-point values.